# css classes not toggling properly based on the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a `div` with a default minus sign and when I click on it it changes to plus sign but when I click on plus sign again it doesn't toggle back to minus sign. How can I alter my javascript so that it switches between the classes based on the click?

```
$(document).on('click', '.header', function (event) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".header").toggle();
    document.getElementById("toggleIcon").className = "icon-plus";
});
```

Default is **icon-minus** and when I click on it it changes to **icon-plus** and when I click on it again it should switch back to **icon-minus** but it is not doing that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion-group" data-bind="foreach: Types">
    <div class="text_x-large header"> 
         <span data-bind="text:Name()"></span> 
         <span id="toggleIcon" class="icon-minus"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <!-- ko if: Letter -->
        <div class="text_x-large letterHeader list_accordion_toggle" data-bind="visible: $parent.ShowLetter(), text: Letter"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="type_list_item smoke_hover" data-bind="template: { name: 'list'}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use toggleClass and address visibility of the element an icon changes through css class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `toggleClass` to switch the classnames as required:

```
$(document).on('click', '.header', function (event) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".header").toggle();
    $("#toggleIcon").toggleClass("icon-plus icon-minus");
});
```

---

> i have multiple divs when i click on the second or third div it only changes the icon for the first div

In that case you should not be using an `id` to select it. Change the `toggleIcon` to a `class`, and use that.

```
$(".toggleIcon", $(this)).toggleClass("icon-plus icon-minus");
```

Comment: this works but because i have multiple divs when i click on the second or third div it only changes the icon for the first div

Answer (score 1):

This way it should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.header', function (event) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".header").toggle();
    if($(this).nextUntil(".header").is(':visible'))
        document.getElementById("toggleIcon").className = "icon-minus";
    else 
        document.getElementById("toggleIcon").className = "icon-plus";
});
```

You've forgotten to set icon minus when the div is opened

Comment: this also works but i have multiple divs in which i am applying this to and the change only affects the first div. when i click on the second or third div only the icon for the first div is changing

Comment: Could you please add your html to your answer? Anyway that's because jQuery is not selecting just the right icon but all icons. My fault. You should use jQuery's traversing utility functions to get the single icon. But to suggest you something I need your html.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I updated my post with the html to take a look

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following line:

```
$("#toggleIcon").toggleClass("icon-minus");
```

.toggleClass() will add the class if it is not present, and remove it, if it is. You can read the full documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Your default style for that icon should be plus, and once icon-minus is added, the image should change. That way you don't need to use more lines of code to add/remove a second class.